# ImageUploadEditor : "Uploaded file is not an image!"

Tags: serenity-platform

I have install Serenity .Net Core 3.1 on a linux centos server.
When I try to upload an image (for example a product image), I have the message :

"Uploaded file is not an image!"

The file is really an image, but the application can not create the image on the server.
The "UploadSettings" in appsettins.json seems correct.
The Directory App_Data/upload/ exists and have the good permissions.

Have you an idea how to resolve this problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: Please share the code you used.

Comment: It is the code of the framework without modification.

Comment: The code works fine on my local workstation. That's why I think it's a configuration issue on the server.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: finally, I upgraded the framework and got a more explicit error message.
The libgdiplus library must be installed: it is used internally to make the image labels.